# How to update tree node size with custom model?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I am using custom model in my [`JTree`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html). When the label of some node changes, I am passing `TreeModelEvent` to the listeners in the following way:

```
       protected void fireNodeChanged(TreePath path) {
            TreeModelEvent evt = new TreeModelEvent(this, path);
            for(TreeModelListener listener : listeners) {
                listener.treeNodesChanged(evt);
            }
        }
```

where `path` is the path to changed node, including itself.

This causes the title change, but the size of it does not:

[image]

Swing truncates the title and adds ellipsis (pointed with red arrow).

How to fix this? Note that I have custom model and can't call [`nodeChanged`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#nodeChanged-javax.swing.tree.TreeNode-), I should emulate it.

Answer (score 0):

Without a snippet there are several guesses to make, but this situation seems familiar to me.
Try adding a renderer to your `JTree` that performs an `updateUI()` on the rendering component before returning it:

```
tree.setCellRenderer(new DefaultTreeRenderer() {
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
            boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row,
            boolean hasFocus) {
        Component c = super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value,
                selected, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
        // You can do more changes here
        ((JComponent) c).updateUI();
        return c;
    }});
```

About the updating, if "emulating" means implementing it and does what's supposed to do, that's correct. As long as it implements `TreeModel` and the methods do what's supposed, `JTree` should do the rest.

The truncation might be related to the fact that trees and tables do not lay their "components" out but use renderers instead to paint them in faked containers.

And, by the way, you can have a look at [`EventListenerList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html) for a proper collection of event listeners.

Comment: `updateUI()` is the wrong method to use here. It is meant for updating the UI after replacing/installing a UI delegate. The change it causes is very radical, and should not be used as a shortcut.

Comment: I well know about that, but in the renderers all the processing happens in the UI delegates, if you use the most recommendable `.invalidate()` the sizes are not calculated properly. As fas as I know, this happens because the renderer component is not placed in a real container neither is layed out, just used to paint a "stamp" that's used for the painting of the `JTree` (or whichever component with renderers). Try it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented `addTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l)` in your custom TreeModel implementation? You'll want to call `treeNodesChanged(TreeModelEvent e)` on any registered listeners when your nodes are modified. Take a look at the source code for `DefaultTreeModel` for an example (the notification propagates up through the node's parents). Or, just have your custom model extend `DefaultTreeModel` and save yourself some time re-implementing all the listener stuff.